# Creating and Exporting a 3 column list in a specific format

Tags: python, solidworks

I'm currently trying to create an Exportable list has 3 columns (x,y,z). In order for Solidworks to read the text file as data, it needs to be in the format:

X,Y,Z

X,Y,Z

X,Y,Z

etc...

Here is the code im having issues with:

```
import math

#Variables
E=1.5 #eccentricity
R=10.4 #Rotor from center to tip
W = 6 #how wide is the housing in the Z drections
Kf = R/E  #K factor of the engine

def range_inc(start, stop, step, inc):
    i = start
    while i < stop:
        yield i
        i += step
        step += inc
theta = list(range_inc(0,(2*math.pi),0.1,0)) #Range for theta

#X and Y equations for the Housing
def X (O):
    return (E * math.cos(3 * O)) + (R * math.cos(O)) # # #
def Y (O):
    return (E * math.sin(3 * O)) + (R * math.sin(O))


#needed lists
HousingDatax = []
HousingDatay =[]
HousingDataz = []
HousingData= []

#creating the housing Data
c=0
for i in theta:
    HousingDatax.append(X(theta[c]))
    c += 1
c=0
for i in theta:
    HousingDatay.append(Y(theta[c]))
    c += 1
c=0
for i in theta:
    HousingDataz.append(0)
    c += 1
c=0

#Grouping the Data for Solidworks
for i in theta:
    HousingData.append([HousingDatax[c],HousingDatay[c],HousingDataz[c]])
    c += 1
print(HousingData)
with open("HousingData.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write(str(HousingData))
```

I am used to Matlab, where matrix formatting is very simple so any and all help is appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You need a combination of [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

```
import csv

#Grouping the Data for Solidworks
data = list(zip(HousingDatax, HousingDatay, HousingDataz))

with open("HousingData.txt", "w", newline='') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

A few notes for Python:

1. You should see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) for naming conventions. The capitalised names should be reserved for classes
2. You should use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) in your loops, instead of having an external counter variable
3. More-generally, there was no need to iterate through `theta` multiple times, you could have done all of that work in a single loop

Comment: after importing CSV that worked perfectly, thank you!